# Error while adding new data in realm in swift

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to create table and add 1st row in realm table.
But getting below error

```
 realm?.write {
            let Model = Feedback()
            Model._id = UUID().uuidString
            Model.data1 = data1
            Model.data2 = data2
            Model.message = message
            realm?.add(Model, update: .all)
        }
```

Feedback model ->

```
class Feedback: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var data1: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var data2: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var message: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
    
}
```

Error I am getting this

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'Feedback' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `Feedback` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'
```

Comment: Which version of Realm you use? I have recently used ```pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.24'``` in my project and it seems fine.

Comment: Looks like you are implementing your object with the old way, try to update RealmSwift and follow the new documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in your question, and it works for me with copy and paste, other than the realm write should be `try! realm.write {`. But.... The error is not from that code (as-is)... that error is a result of doing something with the Feedback before it's been written. Also, as a side note; in computer programming it's Best Practice to use lowercase on the first character of a var name: instead of `let Model = ...` it should be `let model = ...`. Upper case characters are reserved for Classes, Structures, and Enums. It makes the code easier to read.